# Why is it useful to know how to convert between numeric bases?

Tags: base-conversion

We are learning about converting Binary to Decimal (and vice-versa) as well as other base-conversion methods, but I don't understand the necessity of this knowledge.

Are there any real-world uses for converting numbers between different bases?

Comment: Can you give an example of a concrete case?

Comment: Can you work with binary as well as you can with decimal? No? There's a good reason to convert between them.

Comment: How is this question particular to html?

Answer (score 1):

- When dealing with Unicode escape codes— `'\u2014'` in Javascript is `&#8212;` in HTML
- When debugging— many debuggers show all numbers in hex
- When writing bitmasks— it's more convenient to specify powers of two in hex (or by writing `1 << 4`)

Comment: Well, the bitmask example does not involve any conversion between decimal and binary at all because you are treating the bitmask as a string of bits instead of a quantity.

Comment: @Martinho: Until you print their values in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](http://jonnydee.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/convert-a-block-of-digits-from-base-x-to-base-y/) I describe a concrete use case. In short, suppose you have a series of bytes you want to transfer using some transport mechanism, but you cannot simply pass the payload as bytes, because you are not able to send binary content. Let's say you can only use 64 characters for encoding the payload. A solution to this problem is to convert the bytes (8-bit characters) into 6-bit characters. Here the number conversion comes into play. Consider the series of bytes as a big number whose base is 256. Then convert it into a number with base 64 and you are done. Each digit of the new base 64 number now denotes a character of your encoded payload...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a device, such as a hard drive, that can only have a set number of states, you can only count in a number system with that many states.

Because a computer's byte only have on and off, you can only represent 0 and 1. Therefore a base2 system is used.

If you have a device that had 3 states, you could represent 0, 1 and 2, and therefore count in a base 3 system.